# Is there a way to run a single benchmark with sbt-jmh?

Tags: scala, sbt, benchmarking, jmh, sbt-jmh

I am working on a big `sbt` project and there is some functionality that I want to benchmark. I decided that I will be using `jmh`, thus I enabled the `sbt-jmh` plugin.

I wrote an initial test benchmark that looks like this:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark

class TestBenchmark {

  @Benchmark
  def functionToBenchMark = {
    5 + 5
  }
}
```

However, when I try to run it with `jmh:run -i 20 -wi 10 -f1 -t1 .*TestBenchmark.*` I get `java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name`. I have freshly rebuilt the project and everything compiles and runs just fine.

The first printed message says

> Processing 6718 classes from /path-to-repo/target/scala-2.11/classes
>   with "reflection" generator

I find it weird that the plugin tries to reflect the whole project (I guess including classes within the standard library). Before rebuilding I was getting `NoClassDefFoundError`, although the project was otherwise working well.

Since there are plenty of classes within the project and I cannot make sure that every little bit conforms to `jmh`'s requirements, I was wondering if there's a way to overcome this issue and focus and reflect only the relevant classes that are annotated with `@Benchmark`?

My `sbt` version is `0.13.6` and the `sbt-jmh` version is `0.2.25`.

Comment: If I remember correctly you have to use other regular expressions for JMH on the sbt console. More like `\.*TestBenchmark`.

Comment: That produced the same result.

Comment: Do you have your classes under `src/jmh/...`? We don't have any problems although we usually annotate the class itself with things like `@State, @BenchmarkMode` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So this is an issue with Scala and `Class.getSimpleClassName`.

Its not abonormal in Scala to have types like this:

```scala
object Outer {
   sealed trait Inner
   object Inner {
      case object Inner1 extends 
      case object Inner2 extends Inner
   }
}
```

With the above calling `Outer.Inner.Inner1.getClass().getSimpleName()` will throw the exception your seeing.

I don't think it uses the full project, but only for things that are directly referred to in the `State` or `Benchmark`.

Once I had my bench file written that way it worked.